# Обращавшихся или обратившихся

Tags: окончания

Как правильно?
Необходимо узнать количество обращавшихся/обратившихся человек за 2014 год.
И почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Корректны оба варианта: первый вариант подразумевает повторное обращение,т.е. каждый человек обращался больше, чем один раз. В то время как второй вариант подразумевает, что обращение было один раз.

Answer (score 1):

Эти причастия различаются тем, что они образованы от глаголов разного вида: обращаться (несовершенный вид) и обратиться (совершенный вид). И плясать нужно именно отсюда, потому что вид влияет на значение глагола. Обратиться — это непродолжительный процесс, в то время как глагол «обращаться» подразумевает процессуальность действия: оно происходит неоднократно.

Comment: Tagirix, "Обратиться" - это вообще не процесс, здесь однократное действие.

Answer (score 0):

> Как правильно? Необходимо узнать количество обращавшихся/обратившихся
>   человек за 2014 год.

Лучше было бы написать примерно так:

*Необходимо узнать количество человек, обращавшихся/обратившихся **за чем-либо / к кому-либо / куда-либо**  в 2014 году.*